# vectorising while loop insertion sort matlab

Tags: matlab

```
array = [2 1 3 2 1]

for i = 2:length(array)
    value = array(i);
    j = i - 1;

    array_j=array(1:j);
    array_j_indices=cumsum(array_j>value);
    [~,n]=find(array_j_indices==1);
    newArray=array;
    array(n+1:i)=array_j(array_j>value);
    j=j-max(array_j_indices);
    array(j+1) = value;

end %forLoop

disp(array);
```

Hello,
I saw this code for vectorising while loop insertion code but i cannot seem to understand how it works. 
How does `cumsum(array_j>value)` work? I understand and tested cumsum functions but i can't seem to understand how the rational operator of `(array_j>value)` works in the within a cumsum function under the for loop.

Also, i dont understand how `[~,n]=find(array_j_indices==1)` stores value for the matrix of n. Does it store it only in columns because there is a not (~) in the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`cumsum(array_j>value)`?**

`array_j>value`: due to the sorted nature of `array_j`, the result is always some zeros followed by some ones, e.g. `[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]`

`cumsum(array_j>value) = [0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4]`: at most one element will be equal to `1`.

**`[~,n]=find(array_j_indices==1);` ?**

Because there is only one row, this is equal to `n=find(array_j_indices==1);`.

**Fastest implementation?**

Note that this 'vectorised' code is slower the following (easier) implementation:

```
for i = 2:length(array)
    value = array(i);
    j = i - 1;

    n=find(array(1:j)>value,1); 
    array(n+1:i)=array(n:j);
    array(n) = value;
end
```

and much slower than the built-in matlab `sort` method.